# How to Access to Elements Eloquent Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Property Model**

```php
class PostProperty extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'post_properties';

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

**Post Model**

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    public function postproperties()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostProperty');
    }
}
```

**Tables**

[image: Click here]
[image: Click here]

**Sample Output**

$pv this my array: example('car','25','foo')

**Query**

```php
$posts = Post::with('postproperties')
    ->where('type_id', '=', $type)
    ->where(function ($q) use ($title, $pv) {
        $q->orWhere('title', 'like', '%' . $title . '%')
            ->orwhere(function ($qq) use ($pv) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($pv); $i++)
                    $qq->orwhere('property_value', 'like', '%' . $pv[$i] . '%');
            });
    })
    ->get();
```

I need to access the elements of postproperties to put in a query condition.

Comment: Did you mean to eager load properties relation?

Comment: i want create advance search for post and post properties 
yes 
load postproperties relation.
and insert 
where in eloquent with for filter query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $posts = DB::table('posts')
        ->leftJoin('post_properties','posts.id','=','post_properties.post_id')
        ->select('posts.*')
        ->where('posts.type_id','=',$type)
       ->where('posts.verified_at','!=',null)
        ->where(function($q)use($title,$pv){
            $q->orwhere('posts.title','like','%'.$title.'%');
            for ($i=0;$i<count($pv);$i++)
                $q->orwhere('post_properties.property_value','like','%'.$pv[$i].'%');
        })
        ->distinct('posts.id');
```

it's better

Answer (score 0):

solved

```
        $posts = Post::where('type_id','=',$type)
        ->leftJoin('post_properties','posts.id','=','post_properties.post_id')
        ->where(function($q)use($title,$pv){
            $q->orwhere('title','like','%'.$title.'%');
            for ($i=0;$i<count($pv);$i++)
                $q->orwhere('property_value','like','%'.$pv[$i].'%');
        })
        ->groupBy('id')
        ->get();
```